# Python OpenCV mask shows a black image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, object-detection

I'm experimenting with opencv's find contours for object detection. I want it to keep the blue portion of the python logo while masking away everything else, however my masked image is just a black window

I've tried different lower and upper boundary colours, different image forms, but everything results in a black window

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    img = cv2.imread('python logo.png')

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #IMG now displaying in hsv
    lower_sand = np.array([84, 89, 56]) #RGB FORMAT
    upper_sand = np.array([178, 175, 104]) # RGB FORMAT

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_sand, upper_sand)
    cv2.imshow("Masked logo", mask)

    cv2.imshow("Python Logo", img)
```

Comment: The comments suggest that you think you're operating on an RBG image, but you've converted (from BGR, not RGB) to HSV (hue, saturation, value), which is an entirely different space. Take a closer look at https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html

Comment: You can find a script that easily helps you find the proper range values here: https://github.com/twenty-twenty/opencv_basic_color_separator

Comment: Ah sick thank you so much! That script is very useful and my mask works now!!